# Append does not "loop" my search code in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, append

I`m trying to make a code that search (number code called 'cpf') and return me the infos that the url will show. The code works properly with a single cpf, but the append function seens not to work correctly...

```
    def search_cpfs(self):
    names = []
    consigs = []
    cards = []
    for cpf in self.cpfs:
        print(f"Procurando {cpf}.")

        self.driver.get(self.bot_url)

        cpf_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[1]/input')
        cpf_input.send_keys(cpf)

        time.sleep(2)

        cpfButton = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[2]/button')
        cpfButton.click()

        time.sleep(2)

        name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
        consig = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
        card = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span").text

        names.append(name)
        consigs.append(consig)
        cards.append(card)

        print(name, consig, card)

        return names, consigs, cards
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps due to indentation? Your current code shows/returns only one/the first result.

Try this:

```
def search_cpfs(self):
    names = []
    consigs = []
    cards = []
    for cpf in self.cpfs:
        print(f"Procurando {cpf}.")

        self.driver.get(self.bot_url)

        cpf_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[1]/input')
        cpf_input.send_keys(cpf)

        time.sleep(2)

        cpfButton = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[2]/button')
        cpfButton.click()

        time.sleep(2)

        name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
        consig = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
        card = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span").text

        names.append(name)
        consigs.append(consig)
        cards.append(card)

        print(name, consig, card)

    return names, consigs, cards
```

I assume the function is within a class.